What's a "duped sword" in Death Ball and what effects does it have when you buy it?
Recently when researching about Death Ball (roblox) on Fandom and other websites, I received warnings about "duplicate incidents" and "duplicated swords". What are "duplicated swords" or "duplicated incidents" on Death Ball Roblox, and what effects do they have on the player when the player buys these swords?
